# PHP - exec command from server A on server B

Tags: php, exec

I have 2 servers: A and B.

Server A where apache2 is running, tries to execute the following command to create a virtual machine image on server B:

```
ssh -p 22 user@serverB.com fallocate -l 2048M /home/user/images/guest.img 2>&1
```

The output from this command shows a host verification error:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(29) "Host key verification failed."
}
```

I have also tried the following one, but I can not login as www-data:

```
echo myPassword | sudo -S su -c ssh -p 22 user@serverB fallocate -l 2048M /home/user/images/guest.img -s /bin/bash -l user 2>&1
```

This is probably due to the fact that the user executing this command is www-data. Executing the command as 'user' works just fine of course.

How would I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/323629) to a similar question?

Comment: @PatrickQ Just tried that solution which gives me: array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(78) "Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/www/.ssh/known_hosts)."
  [1]=>
  string(36) "Permission denied, please try again."
  [2]=>
  string(36) "Permission denied, please try again."
  [3]=>
  string(39) "Permission denied (publickey,password)."
}

Comment: I've added the file /var/www/.ssh/known_hosts but it still gives me permission denied back.